# IF dentro do While Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Estou fazendo uma verificação de dois campos usando o selenium, quando mando executar o script notei que nunca entra na condição do IF, mesmo atendendo aos requisitos, sempre passa direto para o ELSE.

Alguém sabe dizer o que está errado e como devo ajustar esse script?  Segue o script:

```java
String statusAssincProcess = null;  
String statusAssincProcess2 = null;

while (statusAssincProcess != "Finalizado" || statusAssincProcess2 != "Sucesso"){  
            Thread.sleep(1500);  
            dsl.clicarBotao("ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_btnFiltrar");  
            Thread.sleep(1500);  
            statusAssincProcess = dsl.obterTexto(By.xpath(  
                    "//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_grdServiceStatus_ctl00_ctl04_lbStatus\"]"));  
            statusAssincProcess2 = dsl.obterTexto(By.xpath(  
                    "//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_grdServiceStatus_ctl00_ctl04_lbFinalizadoComErro\"]"));  
            System.out.print("1" + statusAssincProcess);  
            System.out.print("2" + statusAssincProcess2);

            if (statusAssincProcess == "Finalizado" || statusAssincProcess2 == "Erro") {
                    Screenshot.tirar(navegador, "C:\\Users\\servflex050\\Documents\\TST_FATL\\printscreen\\"
                            + nometeste + "_" + Generator.dataHoraparaArquivo() + ".png");
                    statusAssincProcess = "Finalizado";
                    statusAssincProcess2 = "Sucesso";
                } else {
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    dsl.clicarBotao("ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_btnFiltrar");
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Basicamente, para comparar strings se usa `equals`, não `==`. Na pergunta que foi sugerida como duplicata tem uma explicação mais detalhada

Comment: @hkotsubo obrigado pelo auxílio! Li tudo o que foi dito na pergunta sugerida e consegui entender melhor sobre quando usar `==` ou `equals`. Agora a verificação está sendo feita.